# Below pattern code is not working as expected

Tags: java, loops

The below pattern code is not working as expected.

```java
public class pattern_print {
    public static void main (String args[]){
        int i = 1, j = 5, n = 5;
        while (i <= n) {
            while (j >= i) {
                System.out.print("*");
                j--;
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Who can help me?

Comment: What is expected?

Comment: what is the output you get? and what is the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

What are you expecting?
The code that you wrote is displaying the following chars:

```
*****
```

If you want to display something like:

```
*****
****
***
**
*
```

Then the correct code is:

```java
public class pattern_print {
    
    public static void main (String args[]) {
    
        int i = 1, j = 5, n = 5;
    
        while (i <= n) {
            while (j >= i) {
                System.out.print("*");
                j--;
            }
    
            System.out.print("\n");
            j=5;
            i++; 
        }    
    }
}
```

Now depends what you expect to be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

If the following triangle pattern is expected:

```
*****
****
***
**
*
```

the value of `j` needs to be reset to `n` as Andreea Frincu suggested.

However, `for` loops may be more preferable when printing patterns.
Also, since Java 11 released back in Sep 2018 there is method [`String::repeat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#repeat(int)) which allows to avoid redundant nested loops and the same triangle pattern may be printed as simply as:

```java
for (int i = 5; i >= 0; i--) {
    System.out.println("*".repeat(i));
}
```